# The cookie is the whole line?

Tags: c#, cookies, http-headers

There is some server that I upload some file to this server and the server sends me a response, I need to remember the cookie from the server response. the header of the server response looks like this:

```
StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  X-Frame-Options: DENY
  Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
  Connection: Keep-Alive
  Date: Fri, 02 Feb 2018 21:46:49 GMT
  Set-Cookie: re_cookie=EHKJGIMA; Domain=tr.something.com; Expires=Mon, 31-Jan-2028 21:59:44 GMT; Path=/
  Server: CPWS
  Content-Length: 1279
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
}
```

I extracted from the server response the cookie name, that is: `re_cookie` and I also extracted the cookie value, that is `EHKJGIMA`,

The thing is that I'm new with cookies and I'm not sure if I should extract the whole line, I mean this line:

`Set-Cookie: re_cookie=EHKJGIMA; Domain=tr.something.com; Expires=Mon, 31-Jan-2028 21:59:44 GMT; Path=/` or should I only remember `re_cookie=EHKJGIMA` , Thanks.

Comment: All if it is relevant. Domain shows where it is applicable, path it's relevance and expiry date,  when it ceases to be valid.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of that information only applies to [how Browsers handle Cookies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Cookie_attributes). Browsers have to handle a lot of cookies. Possibly hundreds. And they have to send every cookie as part of every request, so filtering wich to actually send maters a lot.

So it is told a lot of secundary inforamtion:

- Wich domains to send those too
- Wich paths to send them too (in case there a special cookies for seperate subpages)
- When to clean up the cookie (at browser closure, a certain intervall or never)

None of those are send by the browser as part of a request. It only sends name and value.

As a general rule, you only need to handle the name and value of a cookie. Only when your programm starts using multiple WebAPI do you have to worry about handling multiple cookies. And even then you propably just handle them via a simple data structure, rather then the complex storage and management a WebBrowser has to do.